# How to get events from wcf service loaded by mef to propagate exceptions to host (self-hosted)

Tags: wcf, events, logging, mef

I have a self-hosted WCF service which load its ServiceContracts with MEF. All works fine. I am also able to send error messages to the WCF Client, which is regarding the faults caused by the user. However I also want to capture all the exceptions that can be caused by the service itself and send them to the Windows service that hosts the WCF Services. In the Windows Service I would like to be able to use the logging system to write this exceptions to. I have already tried the [example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2011/03/16/mef-lab-how-to-keep-implementation-details-out-of-a-mef-contract-assembly-by-implementing-an-interface-based-event-handler.aspx) by David Anson. Another solution I came up with was by using MessageQueues, although I don't think it is a nice solution. Has anyone an idea how to solve this? Preferably with an example...

Comment: In my current implementation, I moved away from the idea to use queues. Instead of that I have used Named Pipe. However I don't think it is the nicest solution...